# adding two matrices with assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am writing an assembly program that will take two 3X6 matrices, adds them, then puts the results into a new matrix. I am running into a few problems.

The issue is it only outputs 2-16 for matrix 1 and 20-34 for matrix 2. I cant seem to figure out how to get it to use the full range.

```
%include "io.mac"
.STACK 100H 
.DATA
 NO_ROWS EQU 3
 NO_COLUMNS EQU 5
 SIZE_OF_ROW EQU 5
 SIZE_OF_ENTRY EQU 2


 matrix1 
 dw 1,2,3,4,5,6
 dw 7,8,9,10,11,12
 dw 13,14,15,16,17,18

 matrix2 
 dw 19,20,21,22,23,24
 dw 25,26,27,28,29,30
 dw 31,32,33,34,35,36

matrix3 TIMES 40 DW 0
 .CODE
 .STARTUP


mov  CX, NO_ROWS ; set outer loop count

L1: ; begin the outer loop   
    push CX ; save outer loop count
    mov BX, CX ;move outer loop count into EAX
    sub bx, 1
    mov CX, 5 ; set inner loop count

L2:
   ; use formula arrayName + (elements_in_a_row*row_number + element) *size_of_entry
mov si, 0
mov di, 0
mov dx, 0
mov si, matrix1
mov di, matrix2
mov ax, SIZE_OF_ROW
mul bx ;multiply ax by which row you're on.
add ax, cx ;then add column count, for which column you're on.
shl ax, 1 ;then multiply it by the size of each entry.
add si, ax ; so that the index points to the element.
add di, ax
mov ax, [si]
add ax, [di]
mov [matrix3], ax
PutInt [matrix3]
nwln
add word [matrix3], 2



    loop L2 ; repeat inner loop
    pop CX ;restore outer loop
    loop L1 ;repeat outer loop




 done:
 .EXIT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner loop `L2` will get executed only 5 times for `cx={5, 4, 3, 2, 1}`. The outer loop will go by `bx={2, 1, 0}` (ok). So in total only 15 values will be used. Also `SIZE_OF_ROW` should be 6, if matrix is 3x6 (also `NO_COLUMNS` and actually why do you need even two constants covering the same logic).

But overall you are just heading in wrong direction. The index calculation is needed when you want particular matrix element ("random" access).

To add two matrices of same size together a sequential access is enough, as you will need to process ALL elements.

And you can even forget how many dimensions the matrices have, as all three (source matrices A and B, and result matrix C) have the same size => they have same amount of total elements.

In your case the matrices are 3x6 = 18 elements. Each element is of `word` size (2 bytes). So each matrix will occupy 36 bytes (or 18 words). You defined them in consecutive way (next row starts right after end of previous = good design).

So procedure like this will do matrix addition: C = A + B for matrices of the same size:

```
; Same-size matrices addition (of 16b word elements): C = A + B
; ds:si = A address, ds:bx = B address
; ds:di = C address, cx = total amount of elements
; modifies: all input registers and ax
matrices_add:
    mov    ax,[si]
    add    ax,[bx]     ; ax = A[i] + B[i]
    mov    [di],ax     ; C[i] = ax
    ; ++i (actually advancing all three pointers instead of using index)
    add    si,2
    add    bx,2
    add    di,2
    ; loop until all elements are added
    dec    cx
    jnz    matrices_add
    ret
```

Now in your case you can call it with these arguments:

```
NO_ROWS     EQU 3
NO_COLUMNS  EQU 6      ; fixed

    ...
    mov    si,matrix1
    mov    bx,matrix2
    mov    di,matrix3
    mov    cx,(NO_ROWS*NO_COLUMNS)
    call   matrices_add
    ; here memory at address matrix3 will contain matrix1+matrix2 elements
    ...
```

Stop using console output for debugging, and get some DOS debugger like Turbo Debugger or CV.EXE (code view) from MS. Or use virtual machine BOCHS which has built-in debugger, that's even more robust solution, capable to debug even bootloaders before the DOS is running.

If you want to display the matrix, rather use separate code, to avoid some unwanted effect during addition and to make debugging easier (for example you can first try to display `matrix1` and exit back to DOS, just to verify the output routine is correct:

```
    ...
    mov    si,matrix3      ; pointer to next element
    ; output 3x6 16b matrix from "si" address
    mov    dx,NO_ROWS
output_matrix_row:
    mov    cx,NO_COLUMNS
output_matrix_line:
    PutInt [si]            ; display next element
    PutCh  ' '             ; make space between elements
    add    si,2            ; adjust pointer to point to next element
    dec    cx
    jnz    output_matrix_line
    nwln                   ; new line
    dec    dx
    jnz    output_matrix_row
    ...
```

As you can see, I again did avoid the "random-access" index of element calculation, accessing them again in consecutive manner, having to do for next element only basic `add si,2`, no slow `mul` or even some complex calculation.

That's what makes code written in assembly fast, that you optimize your algorithm to not do useless instructions, if you will keep calculating full index for every element by doing the `offset = (y*ROW_SIZE + x)*ELEMENT_SIZE`, you will end with slower code than good code written in any half-decent high level language (C, Java, C# ... all those compilers would recognize even two nested loops as optimization opportunity and produce similar code like I wrote in asm, with only single loop going over consecutive offsets).

So before writing any code, you should first make sure you fully understand what you want to calculate, and WHY, and simplify it as much as possible to avoid any redundant operations.

---

Until you will see in debugger stepping over single instruction, what you are doing, you will have very hard time to catch all problems of your code, as you nicely demonstrated with last ~4 questions. I appreciate your stubbornness, but you don't look to be talented enough to proceed further without debugger, get finally some, and learn to use it and go through your older questions + hints from others few more times, to see how much you will be able to replicate + understand fully this time.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions. I will follow your advice.

Comment: @Rubiks BTW your index calculation code was basically correct (the input `cx` was wrong, so that's why it didn't cover full matrix of all elements .. oh, and the ROW_SIZE was wrong too). Redundant, as you can see from my "add" routine which ignores dimensions and goes simply through all elements from index 0 to last index (=M\*N-1), ignoring 2D coordinates completely, but correct, so your problem was with wrong coordinates (would be visible during debugging). So you managed to write the more complex part of code calculating index correctly, and got stuck on the simpler loop part... :)

Comment: I have one more question. If I wanted to rotate matrix 1, what would be the best approach?

Comment: Rubiks: rotate? Transpose or rotate? With big enough matrices it may be cheaper to keep them as they are, and just collect transformations info (you can compose rotate/transpose/flip translations together into one complex info, like in 3D when multiplying of transformation matrices is involved, but here the transformation info would be like 2x2 matrix, starting corner, and direction of row/column) Then the final addition of matrices would use somewhat slower index calculation, incorporating the final transformation of coordinates. With small matrices it's probably cheaper to transform data.

Comment: In your case I would stick with literally transforming the data, so you would get new copy of matrix, with rotated values. The index calculation will be not as simple as in my code (+2, +2), you will have to count 2 dimensions in two nested loops, still if you will check how the indices of elements evolve, you will be very likely capable to avoid full index calculation with `mul`, and use just `add/sub` adjustments to the starting index values (like going +2 over original matrix, and zig-zag update of destination index). Use pen+paper example to get idea what you need, look for patterns.